# loop through a text file and insert a line with batch file

Tags: batch-file, text

I am trying to search through a text file for keywords, then insert a number of lines after a specific line/keyword (not end of file).

My code can find the keywords, however I am struggling to add the lines. My code adds the line to the end of the file, so the bit I need help with is after `:ADD THE TEXT`.

myfile.text looks like:

```
QFU;
text2;
LastUpdate=20180323;
text3;
```

I would like to add a list of static lines after `LastUpdate`, which makes the file look like:

```
QFU;
text2;
LastUpdate=20180323;
Inserted text1
Inserted text2
text3;
```

This is my code:

```
@echo

SET /A COND1=0

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (myfile.txt) do call :process %%i
goto thenextstep
:process
set VAR1=%1
IF "%VAR1%"=="QFU" SET /A COND1=1
IF "%VAR1%"=="QFU" (
msg * "QFU line found !!"
)
:If QFU line is found then look for Last update
IF "%COND1%"=="1" IF "%VAR1%"=="LastUpdate" (
msg * "LastUpdate line found !!"

:ADD THE TEXT
echo. text to be added>>myfile.txt

:reset COND1 to 0
set /A COND1=0
)
```

Comment: Can there be more than one instance of lines beginning with `QFU;` and/or `LastUpdate=`? and if so which if any are you wanting to insert the additional lines beneath?

Comment: Yes, hundreds of QFU and LastUpdate. I would like to insert the lines beneath LastUpdate when it (LastUpdate) follows (not immediately) a QFU line.

Comment: so every "LastUpdate" after the very first "QFU"?

Comment: The first LastUpdate line after a QFU line. Then ignore any other LastUpdate lines until the next QFU line comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :get_insert_index

if not defined index (
    >&2 echo index not defined.
    exit /b 1
)

set "i=0"

(
    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do (
        set /a "i+=1"
        echo %%A

        for %%B in (%index%) do if !i! equ %%B (
            echo --- INSERT
        )
    )
) > myupdate.txt

exit /b

:get_insert_index
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "i=0"
set "qfu="
set "total="

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do (
    set /a i+=1
    set "line=%%~A"

    if "%%~A" == "QFU;" (
        set /a "qfu=!i! + 1"
    ) else if "!line:~,11!" == "LastUpdate=" (
        if defined qfu (
            if !i! gtr !qfu! (
                if defined total (set total=!total! !i!) else set total=!i!
                set "qfu="
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal & set "index=%total%"
exit /b
```

This will insert text after the 1st line starting with `LastUpdate=`,
after the line of `QFU;`, but not the line starting with `LastUpdate=`
which is the next line after `QFU;`.

The label `:get_insert_index` is called and uses a `for` loop
to read `myfile.txt` to get the line index of `LastUpdate=`
mentioned in the above paragraph.
The variable `qfu` stores the line index + 1 of `QFU;` so
`LastUpdate=` cannot be matched on the next line.
If `gfu` and `LastUpdate=` is found and the line index is
greater then `gfu`, then the line index is appended to `total`.
`qfu` is undefined to avoid further matches to `LastUpdate=`
until `QFU;` is matched again.
The loop will end and the global variable `index` is set the
value of `total`. The label returns control back to the caller.

`index` is checked if defined at the top of the script after
the call of the label.
The top `for` loop reads `myfile.txt` and echoes each line read.
The nested `for` loop checks the `index` variable to match the
current line index and if equal, will `echo` the new text.
The echoes are redirected to `myupdate.txt`.

Used substitution of `"!line:~,11!"` so view `set /?` for help.

Used `enabledelayedexpansion` so view `setlocal /?` for help.
Text using `!` may find `!` being interpreted as a variable
so avoid using `!`.

Used `gtr` which can be viewed in `if /?`. `gtr` is
"Greater than".

---

Alternative to avoid creation of an index:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "i=0"
set "gfu="

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do (
    set /a i+=1
    set "line=%%~A"

    >> myupdate.txt echo(%%A

    if "%%~A" == "QFU;" (
        set /a "qfu=!i! + 1"
    ) else if "!line:~,11!" == "LastUpdate=" (
        if defined qfu (
            if !i! gtr !qfu! (
                >> myupdate.txt echo --- INSERT
                set "qfu="
            )
        )
    )
)

exit /b
```

- `>> myupdate.txt echo(%%A` writes each line.
- `>> myupdate.txt echo --- INSERT` writes new line to insert.

If system memory permits based on file size, this is much faster:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "i=0"
set "gfu="

(
    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do (
        set /a i+=1
        set "line=%%~A"

        echo(%%A

        if "%%~A" == "QFU;" (
            set /a "qfu=!i! + 1"
        ) else if "!line:~,11!" == "LastUpdate=" (
            if defined qfu (
                if !i! gtr !qfu! (
                    echo --- INSERT
                    set "qfu="
                )
            )
        )
    )
) > myupdate.txt

exit /b
```

Used on 2.74 MB file, Time reduced from 70s to 21s. The write handle to `myupdate.txt` remains open for the entire loop, thus the write is cached.

Comment: Michael, that's great. Many thanks for that. The code works perfectly with the test file which is 20 KB. For some reason it doesn't work with the original file which is 2.5 MB of size. Do you think there is a fix for that?

Comment: Tested with file size of 2.74 MB. Lines count is about 260,000. Get an error of `The input line is too long.`. Suspect index variable string length exceeding max length. [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation) states 8191 characters is max length. I would have to test alternatives to attempt to overcome the issue.

Comment: Testing file method for the index, will take days or more. I would suggest another language to handle large files. AutoIt can do 16,777,216 elements in an array. AutoIt can do 2,147,483,647 max string length. Python can apparently do 536,870,912 elements in a list. Powershell may have some similar high limits. Going to kill test running for probably more than 30 minutes and output file is only at 90 KB.

Comment: I can write an app in vb.net. Then, unfortunately wait months to get it on company  network. Hence the need for a Batch file. Many thanks for your great efforts.

Comment: Added alternative code to avoid creating the index. I get no error with it so give it a try.

Comment: Michael, It works. I got the result file after about 15 min which is fine. I couldn't thank you more. Very grateful for your help. BTW, would it be possible to recommend a resource for me to learn more about batch scripts?

Comment: Click on the tag of interest and then click on the info tab for i.e [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info). Plenty of links and information about that interest.